# what is the difference between these codes "c sharp , c#"?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FeetToInches(30)); // 360
            Console.WriteLine(FeetToInches(100)); // 1200
            int FeetToInches(int feet)
            {
                int inches = feet * 12;
                return inches;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double inch;
            Console.Write("Input Value (Feet)  : ");
            double feet = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            inch = feet * 12;

            Console.WriteLine("{0} Feet  : {1} Inches", feet, inch);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

i don't understand the upper code i am beginner
and what is meaning of

> int FeetToInches(int feet)

why he wrote return inches; instead of return;

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods

Comment: Have a look at [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) inside C#. They are functions declared inside another function and run within the context of the outer function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int FeetToInches(int feet)` is a method accepting the paramter `feet` of type `int` and defines a return type of `int`.

`return;` can only be used in a method without a return type, `return inches;` returns the variable `inches`

About the difference in your code sample, they differ in a lot of ways, and the only thing they share is `* 12` to calculate feet. But input and output are different.